# how to use find result as part of regex in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, find, xargs

I want to find out which directory doesn't have *.dsc file in it, so I had a try:

```
find . -type d -exec ls {}/*.dsc
```

the output is as below:

```
ls: connot access './abc/*.dsc': No such file or directory
```

I'm sure that there is a dsc file in abc/ directory.
Seems bash shell will treat "{}/*.dsc" as a string but not a regex, so I had another try:

```
find . -type d|xargs -I {} ls {}/*.dsc
```

but the result is the same.
How could I get the command work as I need?

Comment: ls doesn't perform pathname expansion on its arguments, you should either go with Pacifist's answer, or `find . -type d -exec sh -c 'ls -- "$1"/*.dsc' _ {} \;` if you need ls for some reason

Comment: this command line seems most close to what I ask, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to use wildcards in find + ls, but the command below works.

```sh
find . -type d -not -path . | while read -r dir; do [ -f $dir/*\.dsc ] || echo $dir; done
```

It test separately whether a file *.dsc exists and echoes the directory otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your reply. like I said, I want to get to know which directorys don't have dsc file in it, so the whole command would be:

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to get to know which directories don't have dsc file in it, so the whole command would be:`find . -type d |xargs -I {} ls {}/*.dsc && print or remove the directry || do nothing`.  I want to do the check and remove action in a simple line. But seems the -exec option for find and xargs will treat "*" as common string. Is there any way I can do to make the command work?

Comment: Nice! It seems that it doesn't work when a directory has a white space in its name. Rule of thumb: don't use white spaces :p

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one out :

```
find . ! -iname "*.dsc" -type d
```

`!`: This is used to negate the match. It will list everything but files with .dsc extension.

`-type d`: This will fetch all the directories.

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. It prints any directory whether or not a file ending on .dsc exists.